# (node.js) how to use environment variables in JSON file

Tags: node.js

I'm using a 3rd party library that needs a JSON config file, and I need to pass some env variables in as key values. If I include them as I normally would, eg:

```
  "s3": {
    "key": process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    "secret": process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    "bucket": process.env.S3_MLL_BUCKET_NAME,
    "destination": "/backups/database",
    "encrypt": false,
    "region": process.env.AWS_REGION
  }
```

...I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: config/s3_backup.config.json: Unexpected token p
```

Comment: If it doesn't pass the [usual tests](http://jsonlint.com) it's not JSON.

Answer (score 44):

JSON does not have notion of environment variables. What you can do though is to declare your configuration file as `node.js` module and then you will be able to use your environment variables as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  s3: {
    key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    bucket: process.env.S3_MLL_BUCKET_NAME,
    destination: "/backups/database",
    encrypt: false,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
  }
};
```

Comment: It's actually pretty easy got combine this with the content of a JSON file: `merge({ }, defaults, config)` where `var config = require('config.json')` for example if you have a good `merge` function.

Comment: I should have been a little more specific, when I said in the OP that I'm working with a 3rd party lib, I must pass it a JSON file, I can't use a normal js file and export the config. I suppose I could just generate the JSON file as part of my deploy script... though that kind of defeats the purpose of using env variables. I'll check with the author of the project as this seems like too common to not have a workaround.

Comment: You could generate JSON file from the module via 'JSON.stringify()' call and pass it to the library.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem as Ben, "stringifying" the js object doesn't work either.

Comment: I too have the same problem exactly, the third party library will look for a json file in perticular directory. I can't use the mudules to export or strigify.

Comment: JSON does not support variables, period. So you need to use a workaround. This is just one of the possible workarounds.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone is still having this problem but to caveat off of @dtoux answer, requiring dotenv and calling require('dotenv').config() in the module will set the env var values.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was using a js file and exporting an object `module.exports = {config: {"exampleAPIKey":"ruier4343"}}`...then "stringifying" the object and then parsing it back to json 
`const config = require("./jsConfigs.js").config;
const jsonConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config))`
I had tried it so many different ways but this is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue where i have to pass Env variables inside config.json and my 3rd party system accepts mainly config.json.

Here is the workaround that worked for me.

1. My app.js gets executed inside start script of package.json
2. So During Runtime (i.e deployment which runs command 'npm run start') it will update config.json dynamically using below code placed inside app.js (before creating server).

**App.js**

```js
    //updating config.json to use environment variables during run time
    const fs = require('fs');
    const fileName = './public/config.json';
    const file = require(fileName);
    if (file && file.arguments && file.arguments.execute)
        file.arguments.execute.url = process.env.executeUrl || "";

    if (file && file.configurationArguments && file.configurationArguments.publish)
        file.configurationArguments.publish.url = process.env.publishUrl || "";

    fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file, null, 2), function writeJSON(err) {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        console.log('updated config.json');
    });
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('App Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```