# Environment variables in angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular-cli

`angular-cli.json` has lots of great config stuff. deployUrl lets you set the url where files will bee deployed. But this is different for development and production. How can I set this to different values in dev and prod? Can I access environment variables in `angular-cli.json`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject environment variables in a json file. It's not code.

There are a few workarounds though.

Here is one that might help you: [(node.js) how to use environment variables in JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962601/node-js-how-to-use-environment-variables-in-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

The config variables in `angular-cli.json` can also be passed as params to `ng build`. So just set everything in `angular-cli.json` to your dev env. Then anything that needs to be overwritten for prod can be passed to ng build. `ng build -prod --deploy-url=$CDN_PATH`