# How do I use environment variables or mask secrets in package.json?

Tags: reactjs, git, postgresql, environment-variables, package.json

Here's an excerpt from my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=prod npx ./bin/www",
    "migrate": "node-pg-migrate",
    "migrate_dev": "DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dev_db NODE_ENV=dev node-pg-migrate",
  },
```

I'm excluding my `.env` file in `.gitignore` to ensure my secrets don't leak into the git repo. What I want to know is, what's the best way to deal with the `username:password` part of the `migrate_dev` script?

(And I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962601/node-js-how-to-use-environment-variables-in-json-file), but I'm pretty sure I can't use a `.js` file as a `package.json` stand-in.)

I tried assigning environment variables to environment variables, e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "migrate_dev": "DATABASE_URL=DEV_DB_URL NODE_ENV=dev node-pg-migrate",
    ...
  },
```

but, sadly they aren't defined at this point - #bootstraps!  ;-)

Comment: The secrets you're referring to are all in your `.env` file, right?

Comment: you would deal with this by using existing shell tools. Consider having an external script triggered by the package.json rather than trying to fit it all in-line in the scripts block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use environment variables or mask secrets in package.json?
>
> I'm excluding my .env file in .gitignore to ensure my secrets don't leak into the git repo.

Because your secrets are in your `.env` file, they can only be accessed programmatically, and `package.json` does **not** have that capability on its own. This would require a `.js` file.

You can run a `.js` file (i.e. `migrate_dev.js`) from your `migrate_dev` script:

```
"migrate_dev": "node migrate_dev.js"
```

Inside `migrate_dev.js` you should have access to your`.env` file and `node-pg-migrate`'s Programmatic API (its CLI equivalent for JS):

https://salsita.github.io/node-pg-migrate/#/api

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Actually, I hadn't seen that page... and turns out that there's a -d option for specifying the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable! So I can just define a heap of `.env` variables, and hardcode them in the `package.json` file, e.g. `"migrate": "node-pg-migrate",
    "migrate_dev": "NODE_ENV=dev node-pg-migrate -d DEV_DB_URL",`