# env in json config file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to process.env on config.json file, here is my code:

```
{
    "token": process.env.token,
    "application_id": "972740021170303027"
}
```

but when I try to start I'm getting this error

```
SyntaxError: /home/runner/Sniper/sniper/config.json: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 12
```

Anyone knows how to add env to config?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962601/node-js-how-to-use-environment-variables-in-json-file). Is that correct?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(node.js) how to use environment variables in JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962601/node-js-how-to-use-environment-variables-in-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

var jsonData = {
"name": "Miri",
"surname": "Hasanov",
"age": 30,
"test": {
"test1": "test1",
"test2": {
"test2": "test2"
}
}
};

function flattenObject(obj, parentKey = '') {
let result = {};

```
for (const key in obj) {
    const currentKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}_${key}` : key;
    const value = obj[key];

    if (Object.isExtensible(value) && typeof value === 'object') {
        Object.assign(result, flattenObject(value, currentKey));
    } else {
        //for return
        result[currentKey.toUpperCase()] = value;

        //for set proccess
        //proccess.env[currentKey.toUpperCase()] = value;
    }
}

return result;
```

}

console.log(flattenObject(jsonData));

```js
var jsonData = {
    "name": "Miri",
    "surname": "Hasanov",
    "age": 30,
    "test": {
        "test1": "test1",
        "test2": {
            "test2": "test2"
        }
    }
};

function flattenObject(obj, parentKey = '') {
    let result = {};

    for (const key in obj) {
        const currentKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}_${key}` : key;
        const value = obj[key];

        if (Object.isExtensible(value) && typeof value === 'object') {
            Object.assign(result, flattenObject(value, currentKey));
        } else {
            //for return
            result[currentKey.toUpperCase()] = value;

            //for set proccess
            //proccess.env[currentKey.toUpperCase()] = value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(flattenObject(jsonData));
```