# read .env value and use in package.json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, npm, package.json

I have a dependency in my package.json that's doing this

```
{
  "my-lib": " "git+https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myOrg/my-lib.git#v1.0.0"
}
```

How can I store token in .env and use it in package.json? exposing token in git is a bad practice.

Comment: `package.json` is a JSON file, JSON does not have notion of environment variables. more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962601/node-js-how-to-use-environment-variables-in-json-file

Comment: It's specific to your case (using a token for git dep), the question doesn't make sense in general. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency

Comment: @EstusFlask it makes sense because it worked, is it ok to expose my token in package.json?

Comment: @ViennaJ Seems reasonable to me, or use git+ssh, as suggested in the first answer

Comment: @EstusFlask I stick with PAT as I can restrict their permission to read only, no harm